# Webpack Encore with Babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, webpack-encore

I'm getting the following error in my browser console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

I found a question and answer here that said to install Babel to get this working, so I set out to do just that. Now for context, I've never used Webpack Encore nor Babel before now. I've never needed to. I added the below lines to my Webpack Encore file and got another error.

```js
Encore.configureBabel(() => {}, {
    useBuiltIns: 'usage',
})
```

```
[ encore ] Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
RangeError: [BABEL] \resources\js\app.ts: Invalid Option: The version passed to `corejs` is invalid. Currently, only core-js@2 and core-js@3 are supported. (While processing: "\\node_modules\\@babel\\preset-env\\lib\\index.js")
    at normalizeCoreJSOption (\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\normalize-options.js:114:11)
    at normalizeOptions (\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\normalize-options.js:126:18)
    at \node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js:271:37
    at \node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:22:12
    at async (\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\gensync-utils\async.js:43:33)
    at async (\node_modules\gensync\index.js:186:15)
    at \node_modules\gensync\index.js:216:13
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at \node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:217:21
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

With that error, I add `corejs: '3.0.0',` below the `useBuiltIns` and I'm getting more errors. Another question I found suggested that corejs would just render `useBuiltIns: 'usage'` obsolete.

This is all getting to be a little too much for async/await functionality. Functionality that works in my browser.

Comment: Have you tried manually installing `core-js@3`? E.g.: `npm install core-js@3` / `yarn add core-js@3`?

Comment: I haven't tried @Domi but that goes back to the point I made where corejs just renders `useBuildIns: 'usage'` obsolete and I don't want that.

Comment: I don't know how `encore` works, but `useBuiltIns` is not deprecated at all. However, it is not a general `babel` option, but an option of the `preset-env` preset. You probably just need to move it to the right place. - Docs here: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins

Comment: @Domi No one said `useBuiltIns` was deprecated and I do have the option in the right spot for Encore.

Comment: I must have misread. Either way, the code you pasted largely diverges from [the encore documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/babel.html). I don't see any place that uses `configureBabel` like you, with 2 arguments, the second being an object. They always seem to want you to modify the existing `babelConfig` object in the callback that is the first argument, instead. There, you would want to `push` (or look for an existing) `preset-env`, to which you would add `useBuiltIns`. But that's just of their doc page, as I have no xp in Encore.

Comment: @Domi https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/pull/521

Comment: In that case, to circle back to the original problem: You said "Another question I found suggested that corejs would just render useBuiltIns: 'usage' obsolete.". Why do you say that? It is also [one officially recommended approach](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#corejs). All I can say is that I usually use something like `{ useBuiltIns: 'usage', corejs: 3.15 }`, and it works fine. Of course, you want to make sure to also manually install whatever `core-js` version you are referencing.